# Write a report of what the shell would done

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, insert, ksh

In my UNIX shell script I need to insert a parameter to start it. This parameter can assume two valors (test and production). Inside the code I make an insert in an Oracle db. After this insert I have to make a condition that if the parameter is `test` then write the spool in another file and don't connect the db, else connect the db and make the insert normally. Fundamentally there are two ways; in the test I just want to see what the shell is going to do and the production that it makes the normal insert and his operations. I try this after the insert but I get a error:

```
if [[ "$choice" = "test" ]];
then  
  ${TMP_PART2DAT} > ${TMP_REPORT}
else
  SP_SQLLOGIN="$ORACLE_DB_OWN/$ORACLE_PWD@$ORACLE_SID"
  sqlplus -S -L ${SP_SQLLOGIN} @${TMP_PART2SQL}   
fi
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `TMP_PART2DAT` holds the name of a file that contains the SQL command(s)? If so do you just want to copy (or `cat` as you have the `>` redirect) that file to the name held in `TMP_REPORT`? That seems to simple, but if it isn't that then I'm not sure what you're asking. (Incidentally, it might be safer to have your `if` test that the value is *not* the production value; otherwise you might get a nasty surprise if you misspell `'test'` at runtime.)

Comment: The `TMP_PART2DAT` is a spool and contains the datas. The Query is in another file named `TMP_PART2SQL`. What i want is simply redirect the datas inside the first file into another file. But in the way i wrote not works i don't know why..It says `TMP_PART2DAT  not found.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
cat ${TMP_PART2DAT} > ${TMP_REPORT}
```

for line 3 of your script.

This will overwrite everything in TMP_REPORT with the contents of TMP_PART2DAT.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your shell script with "bash -x" mode. You would be able to trace the command execution.